# I am an E-2 Visa holder. Can i get any health insurance

Tags: usa, visa, health-insurance

I have been issued an E-2 5 years multiple entries visa and i was wondering if i can get health insurance in the US for myself and my family (Who also have a E2 5 years multiple entries visa).

What would be the process of health insurance when i arrive in the US?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually your employer will offer health insurance for you and your spouse and children.

If they do not, then you can purchase insurance from your state's health insurance (Obamacare) exchange, or purchase insurance directly from insurance companies.

Comment: Hi, any help here please? https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/12050/citizenship-limitations-for-e2-visa Thanks